# What is the required representation, in the custom.css file of Jupyter Notebooks? (ex: cm-tag)

Tags: css, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

[image: Screenshot from a Jupyter Notebooks cell]

**Example:** In order to set colour for the things like `<br>`, I should use `cm-tag` in order to represent this type in the custom.css file

**Question:** In order to represent the other type of things that I circled in the screenshot, what should I use instead of `cm-tag`?